# ssh to home computer without real IP

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, dynamic-ip

I have a PC running on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and I want to connect to it via ssh. I've found some solution on the net and installed sshd service, but I cannot connect to my PC because I have no real IP address. I'm connected to internet via local network, I mean that I'm  into a local network with my internet provider and they assign me a dynamic IP address anytime I connect and of course I have no access to their routing configurations and I cannot ask them to change something for me. Is there any solution for this situation?

P.S. I also have Ubuntu 11.10 x64 on my PC, so maybe there is a easier solution for Linux.

Comment: I even cannot share my 80 port with others, 80 port opens user account page of that particular user of my provider

Comment: Most ISPs assign you a dynamic ip address. Are you saying that your connection is not active 24/7 or something? You need to be confused by some of the more basic networking terms.  Its a trivial task to change the port on a ssh connection.

Comment: Technically, *all* IP addresses you have are *real*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reverse SSH tunneling](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling) would do the trick - in short, you get the computer that is behind the nat to connect *to* the other system's ssh server. You'd have to work out some way to initiate that - possibly some quick and dirty scripting and crontab running the processe to initiate a tunnel every so often, or using an always on system as an intermediary.

An alternative would be to set up some form of configuration free VPN that uses another server as a intermediary - [hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29) comes to mind but there's other alternatives that might work.

Edit: [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) might automate the reverse ssh process from the system behind the nat, which would make things simpler

Comment: and what if both source and destination have the same case? :)

Comment: you could use another publicly accessible system in between i suppose. You need *at least* one publicly accessible system for SSH to work - you could for example set up a Reverse SSH [threesome](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Reverse_Tunneling). Perhaps something like [TINC](http://www.tinc-vpn.org/) might help in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to sign up to something like DynDNS. They have a free servive. This provides you with the ability to connect to something like myaccount.xxx.net or similar rather than an IP.

Comment: yes, I know about that, but my problem is not the dynamic IP, it's in the routing in the local network of my internet provider, they don't forward ports to my computer

Answer (score 0):

Hamachi or any other VPN solutions with NAT-traversal